# Equivalent of HttpVerbs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

```
public FakeHttpRequest(string relativeUrl, Uri url, Uri urlReferrer)
        : this(relativeUrl, **HttpVerbs.Get.ToString("g"),** url, urlReferrer,
              null, null, null, null)
    {

    }
```

Trying to find the equivalent of HttpVerbs which is a string method, from System.Web.Mvc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest match is `HttpMethods`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpmethods?view=aspnetcore-7.0

It contains named constants for strings POST, PUT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

HttpVerbs isn't part of the new asp.net-core package so instead, I went to the aspnet webstack on CodePlex and used the HttpVerbs class from there and created a class in my project.

Answer (score -3):

You can use:
System.Net.HttpStatusCode

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The question is about Verb, not about status code. Please revise your answer.